# PHP Echo and HTML Mix Multiple Approaches

Tags: php, echo

I am using WAMP to run a local PHP/Apache server. I'm trying multiple approaches to echo lines using HTML tags but the site breaks. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    $name = 'John';
    $months = array('January', 'February', 'March');

    echo "<p>$name;</p>";
?>

    <p><?php echo "Hello World!";?></p>
    <p><?php echo "My name is " . $name . ", nice to meet you.";?></p>
<?php
    echo "<p>Hi again, my name is " . $name . ".</p>";
?>

<?php
    foreach ($months as $current_month) {
        echo "<li>$current_month</li>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser output is

```
$name;
"; ?>
Hi again, my name is " . $name . ".
"; ?>
```

I also tried putting the php code above the Doctype but the site breaks again.

Thank you.

Comment: Check your apache configuration.  You may have problems with the php mime/type so your apache is not recognizing that you are processing a php file so it thinks its a standard html file.

Comment: What is the name of your file? If it doesn't end in .php, then it won't be processed as a PHP file.

Comment: Yes the file has the .php extension. It worked before I added the foreach loop now even if I take it out, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Create a file that contains ONLY `<?php echo "Hello, World!" ?>` if that does not work properly, your Apache setup is wrong.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work even with that, something's wrong but I don't know what. All I changed was error_reporting but then I set it back to default and I restarted the server.

Comment: have you tried using single quote instead of double quote to echo something?

Comment: @s3polz Yes, that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write the code as you're doing. For example this:

```
<p>echo $name;</p>;
```

is totally wrong and should be written like this:

```
echo "<p>$name</p>";
```

Comment: Ah yes sorry I am new to PHP. I fixed it to the right syntax but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: In other words, you can't mix html code directly into php and expect it to work because the php engine will try to execute the html code as php thus you'll end up with syntax errors

Comment: @TheShadowbyte Ok, update your post with the code fixed and the new output you see

Comment: @tffd I'm using the <?php ?> syntax though? It's a .php file as well.